Can God Consider Himself to Be Wrong?
The Hebrew Bible has at least 2 places where God changes course or even regrets his actions. Does that mean God from the Biblical perspective can consider Himself to be wrong?
I'm not asking from our human perspective whether God can be wrong, but is it possible from God's perspective that God can be wrong?
I'm defining wrong as "Someone looking back at their past action and deciding that if given the chance again they would have made a different decision." So for example I'm not asking whether from our perspective God was "wrong" to make Saul King. I'm asking whether God can look at that decision and decide for Himself whether He "should" have made someone else king instead of Saul.
Note: The argument being made against my question is that because God can see the future, God can't be wrong. My response is if a man is born who sees the future, does that mean they can never be wrong?  Then the goalpost was moved to: God can see all potential futures and therefore God can't be wrong. Paul Atreides in Dune is given this power, to see all potential realities, and he chooses something called the Golden Path. Does that inherently lead to a fact that Paul can't ever consider himself wrong? It seems to me Paul could decide he was wrong, but I'm not sure anyone who doesn't have that level of omniscience could say Paul is wrong.
My preference is answers that are more based on scripture. I'm open to all answers, but bringing me an answer that just rewrites or ignores the Bible for the sake of some non biblical dogma is not satisfying for an answer. For example saying God doesn't have emotions means ignoring/rewriting a large and consistent part of our Biblical tradition. Or just ignoring Abraham Abinu who implied that God can be wrong or at least act unjustly.
כה  חָלִלָה לְּךָ מֵעֲשֹׂת כַּדָּבָר הַזֶּה, לְהָמִית צַדִּיק עִם-רָשָׁע, וְהָיָה כַצַּדִּיק, כָּרָשָׁע; חָלִלָה לָּךְ--הֲשֹׁפֵט כָּל-הָאָרֶץ, לֹא יַעֲשֶׂה מִשְׁפָּט.     25 That be far from Thee to do after this manner, to slay the righteous with the wicked, that so the righteous should be as the wicked; that be far from Thee; shall not the Judge of all the earth do justly?'
In other words, Abraham is implying that if God wipes away the wicked with the just in the city, like God seemed to be saying he was going to do, Abraham implies this would make Gods actions unjust.

He can see the future...?

https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.6.6.1

@LaniedSofey If a man was born who could see the future, would that make them incapable of being wrong?

How do you define "being wrong"?

@DoubleAA Looking back at a prior decision and believing inside you should have made a different choice

@Aaron He can also see all possible outcomes at all times

@LaniedSofey If a man was born who could see all possible outcomes, does that mean they become incapable of being wrong?

@Aaron man does not always now what is right and wrong. He does.

@LaniedSofey If I followed your logic then I would expect the Bible to never say that God regrets His decisions. But that's not what the Bible says

@RabbiKaii I do not disagree with you but I think that many of the comments made in the last 2 hours reflect exasperation with the premise of the question. An exasperation that I share.

@Deuteronomy This question does not answer my question. Because the questioner and the answers are all approaching it from our perspective. "Rav Hirsch states (on Noach 6:6) that this is not a matter or "regretting" a decision (as a man would regret a mistake), but that the expression of Man's free will caused an external series of events" so basically God's opinion of His Own Actions are washed away in reframing things from our perspective/free will situation.

Upon being pressed by @DoubleAA about how you define being wrong your answer is "Looking back at a prior decision and believing inside you should have made a different choice"... If that is so, despite different framing, I do not see how your question is significantly different in substance than "How can G-d regret anything?"

@Deuteronomy It seems to me the How can be God be wrong question already rejects the idea that God CAN be wrong. Because as LaniedSofey points out, people accept dogmatic notions that God knows all the future, but not only that, knows all possible futures, and therefore the underlying assumption they insert is that God CAN'T be wrong. But if I say replace the word God with say Paul, and Paul knows the future and all possible futures due to his spice intake, people don't jump to the conclusion that Paul "can't be wrong."

@Deuteronomy Few people will say Paul "can't be wrong," but will instead say Paul will have to choose between different outcomes. And even if Paul agrees with the moral values of the outcome, it seems entirely possible that Paul would still be able to regret, and possibly feel like he made the wrong decision.

I don't know that few people would claim that an omniscient person (were such a thing possible) can be wrong. However if you reject the premise that God is omniscient then I suggest editing your question to reflect that as an aspect of how you are approaching this question and differentiating it from others that already exist.

@Deuteronomy I don't necessarily reject the omniscience of God. It just doesn't seem to me that if we made a Human who was omniscient that then what follows is a literal impossibility for that man to think they could be wrong about themselves. Therefore I don't accept the argument that just because God is omniscient they can't be wrong

I genuinely do not see how posing the impossible hypothetical of an omniscient human changes anything  I'm struggling to see why you think the analysis would be different and that therefore this question is somehow different.

Regarding your latest edit: A) This re-writes your question in a way that precludes answers already proffered (and therefor goes against policy: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/policy-regarding-changing-questions-after-a-period-of-time/1231#1231 ) B) What "biblical tradition" are you speaking of that exists independent of Judaism? We are the progenitors and inheritors of said tradition. Answers here are going to be through that lens.

@Deuteronomy I've upvoted both answers here as they are legitimate ways to answer the question in the Jewish tradition which encompasses written and oral sources. As well as people bringing the opinion and views of Rabbis. Nothing wrong with that. I'm just stating that having a Rabbi say all the emotions, regrets, etc of God are just mistakes and should be considered dreams, or ignored, or forgotten isn't a satisfying answer to me.

@Deuteronomy There is a Karaite Biblical tradition, Ethiopian Jewish Biblical tradition, Masoretic Biblical Tradition, Septuagint Biblical Tradition. These are all Jewish Biblical traditions, two of them have different books than the others

@Aaron again, you are changing the parameters of your question after there are upvoted submitted answers. As for the "biblical traditions" you mention, they are all spin-off "traditions" of our tradition (other than Masoretic, which is part and parcel). Furthermore, if you intend that your question be answered through one of those particular prisms, then it ought be stated. At this point, we have exceeded what is appropriate for the comments section. IMHO this should be closed. All the best.

@Deuteronomy I was talking with a Rabbi who said love your neighbor as yourself only applies to Jews according to Rabbis. I said I disagreed and the Rabbi became irate because the view he shared is "the view." And so I said "Is it okay to lust after my neighbors wife because they aren't Jewish? Can I be jealous of non Jewish houses and fortune because they aren't my neighbor?" His answer is nice, it's the official answer, doesn't mean I find it satisfying.

All that just to say that you find Rabbinic Judaism dissatisfying? Okay...take care.

@Deuteronomy I don't find Rabbinic Judaism dissatisfying. I don't enjoy Rabbinic Jews who act like the one way they view the religion is the only way the religion can be viewed. If someone stated they would prefer an answer based on Rabbinic sources instead of Biblical sources, then that's how I'd answer the question. I don't know why the reverse seems so problematic to you

I don't find the reverse "problematic" (insofar as this forum is concerned), what I find problematic is a retroactive insistence on some sort of unstated biblical literalism on your part not initially expressed in your questions. The vast majority of users are coming from the background of Rabbinic Judaism and then you are frustrated and critical when answers are proffered from that vantage. I don't see much else productive coming of this, so I am stopping here. All the best.

@Deuteronomy I have no issue with Rabbinic answers to this question. But a Rabbinic answer that is just "don't read it that way, disregard it's straightforward meaning altogether for this separate dogma that can only be dated til after the closing of the Bible." I find that unsatisfactory. I would much prefer a Rabbinic answer that doesn't insist on rewriting the text on these matters. But I don't know if there are any?

doesn't Deuteronomy 32:4 imply that He cannot be wrong?

@User123 It does imply that. Feel free to answer with it

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/examples-of-hashem-changing-his-mind-is-the-explanation-always-the-same

@Aaron, how do you understand the change from "if you eat from it, you will surely die that day" to "you will live to about 1000 years old, have kids that will continue forever, and then you will die"? Just curious about your opinion. Maybe it was another "I was wrong" moment? He realised He didn't want to lose Adam and co. afterall, and came up with a plan B

@RabbiKaii I'm willing to answer your question in private. My question itself has -4 score and I can't imagine it will get better if I share my opinion to your question. Can we exchange contact details of some form?

@Aaron yes, and i replied, check your spam

In Derech Mitzvotecha Mitzvat Haamanat Elokut 7, the Tzemach Tzedek teaches us how to resolve these issues about Hashem having emotions brought up by the philosophers and Kabbalists, and concludes that indeed, the descriptions about Hashem in the Torah are meant to be taken as both trancendant beyond our comprehension in unity and ineffability, but also that they are real and true. Our "version" of love, regret etc, is just a mashal for His real and infinite love and regret etc.

וְיִתָּכֵן כִּפְשׁוּטוֹ בֶּאֱמֶת מַה  שֶּׁכָּתוּב
And [the Torah's descriptions] may be truly explained by the simple
meaning of what is written

Seeing as we are on Chassidus, I will give the Chassidic answer and hopefully it will satisfy someone who wants to hear an answer that isn't hard to gel with the Tanach without extensive reasoning.
The Chassidic answer is that the purpose of creation is for Hashem to get married, and have a Home with Yisrael (see Tanya for example). This explanation is based on the various pasukim that describe how Hashem will dwell with us, how he rescued us from Egypt to be ours and for us to be His, and many Nevi'im and Ketuvim on this subject.
Anyone who pursues relationships, especially marriage, knows that there are many ups and downs, regrets, and full on "I wish I had never done this in the first place" moments! Afterall, we are trying to unite with someone else, a true someone as complicated, dynamic, and unpredictable as ourselves. Of all the "problems to solve" in the world, this is by far the hardest - making a perfect marriage.
We need to add this answer into the mix, as it brings the various opinions that state that Hashem doesn't know what we are going to choose. We truly are "other" to Him in that sense, which means that our relationship with Him is just as dynamic and rich - as is clearly depicted in the Torah's narrative of this plan. The many times He regrets, changes His mind, tries to back out, reconciles etc. demonstrate a very familiar image of a real and true marriage.
The one thing I will say though, is that Chassidus will not entertain that Hashem can be wrong. I don't think that matters here though, because it just means that "Hashem can solve any problem". He will one day be married, and it will be a perfect marriage, and we will see the infinite rightness of it. We will thank His omnipotent Hashgacha for solving all the problems and producing the perfect end result despite them. We will also "take the blame" for the difficult problem we presented Him to solve!
There may be times when Hashem feels like He shouldn't have done this or that, or had done this or that differently, but in terms of His vast and eternal plan, He makes no mistakes. His plan is right, perfect and true, and no matter what route is taken to get there, all was meant to be.

B"H

The Bible has at least 2 places where God changes course or even
regrets his actions. Does that mean God can consider Himself to be
wrong?

First of all: no.
Second, I'm assuming you're referring to the flood, and making Shaul King. In the talmud, which is also accepted the same way as the written Torah is, it says that He regretted 4 things:

ארבעה מתחרט עליהן הקדוש ברוך הוא שבראם ואלו הם: גלות, כשדים, וישמעאלים
ויצר הרע - There are four that the Holy One, Blessed is He, regrets
having created. And these are they: The exile, the Chaldeans, the
Ishmaelites, and the evil inclination.

Not only that, but elsewhere in the talmud during a debate, a heavenly voice called out to say a specific rabbi was right as opposed to the majority, to which the other rabbis said that the Torah is not in heaven, then the "Holy one, blessed be He" says my children have defeated me.
A deeper question would be, if Hashem is always "right", and knows the future, why does He allow people to go against His will? Isn't that "wrong"?
But no. There's different ways Hashem relates to the world. Relative to the Awtsmoos, or even higher revelations of the Ohr Ein Sof, everything that has is and will happen, even things people do, is already planned out from the beginning. There is no wrong, everything is exactly as it should be
Before getting into more sources for that, an obvious reference is when the angels asked Hashem why He was causing Rabbi Akiva to suffer, to which Hashem told them to be quite, lest He bring the world back to chaos as it was in the beginning.
It's explained that in order for Hashem to explain why that was happening, He would have to "unravel" the entire universe back to it's origins to show us why it should happen. Without all of that context, it's impossible to know.
Anyways, all the times we see Hashem regretting something, that's only referring to lower levels of how Hashem limits Himself into the system of the world in some way. But I'm Essence, everything is planned out by Him, including right and wrong itself, and He regrets nothing.
Since you asked specifically about how Hashem "regretted" appointing Shaul, it's explained:

ג) והנה הטעם על זה שההעלם וההסתר דהגלות (כולל גם ההעלם וההסתר דדרא
דעקבתא דמשיחא) הוא רק על כחות הפנימיים דהנשמה ולא על מדת הנצח, מבאר
בהמאמר35, שזהו לפי ששרש הנצח36 הוא בעצם הנפש, דכמו"כ הוא למעלה, ששרש
הנצח הוא בפנימיות הכתר, ובפנימיות הכתר לא שייך ענין השינוי.
וכמ"ש37 וגם נצח ישראל לא ישקר ולא ינחם כי לא אדם הוא להנחם, דענין
הנחמה והשינוי שייך רק בבחינת אדם, השתלשלות, ומכיון ששרש הנצח הוא
בבחינת לא אדם, למעלה מהשתלשלות, לכן אין שייך בו שינוי, וישנו בגילוי גם
בזמן הגלות. ולא עוד, אלא שבזמן הגלות, ובפרט בעקבתא דמשיחא, כח הנצחון
והמס"נ הוא בגילוי יותר מבזמן הבית38.
The reason for the concealment and hiding in the time of exile
(including the concealment and hiding during the generation of the
footsteps of the Messiah) affecting only the inner faculties of the
soul and not the attribute of Netzach (eternity/victory) is explained
in the discourse. It is stated that the root of Netzach is in the
essence of the soul. Similarly, above, the root of Netzach is in the
innermost part of Keter (the crown), and within the innermost part of
Keter, the concept of change does not apply. As it is written, "The
Eternity of Israel will not lie nor repent, for He is not a man to
repent." The concepts of repentance and change apply only within the
realm of "man," i.e., within the chain of creation (hishtalshelut).
Since the root of Netzach is in the realm of "not man," beyond
hishtalshelut, it is not subject to change and remains revealed even
during exile. Moreover, during the time of exile, and especially in
the generation of the footsteps of the Messiah, the power of victory
and self-sacrifice is more revealed than during the time of the
Temple.

In other words, the idea of "regret", for example when appointing Shaul, is only in "lower" levels of Seder Histalshilus; but in the "inner dimension of the crown", which is the root of long David's kingdom, there's no concept of change.
I also assume you're referring to how Hashem "regretted" making man, even though you don't say so explicitly.
It's a similar idea, Hashem in Essence knows what He's doing, but in the context of the limitations and revelations there's differences, which can be changed based on the sacrifices that Noach offered afterwards, specifically through the sacrifices that He offered did Hashem say that He will no longer destroy man, even though the same reason given (for man is bad from His youth) was the same reason He used to destroy them in the first place.. the difference of the change of opinion (within Seder Histalshilus) is the sacrifices, because the sacrifices "ascend to the Ein Sof", implying that in the Ein Sof itself there was never any question or regret.
Reasons why the sacrifices caused Him to "change" His mind:

בס"ד. ש"פ נח, תרד"ע וירח ה' את ריח הניחוח ויאמר לא אוסיף עוד לקלל כו',
ואי' במד"ר הריח ריח של אברהם אבינו עולה מכבשן האש, הריח ריח של חנני'
מישאל ועזרי' עולה מכבשן האש כו'. וצ"ל מהו"ע שהריח ריח של אברהם אבינו
וחמו"ע ועי"ז דוקא א' לא אוסיף עוד כו', והלא ע"פ פשוט ריח הניחוח הוא
ריח הקרבנות שהקריב נח שזה ג"כ ענין גבוה ונעלה דרזא דקורבנא עולה עד רזא
דא"ס כו', מה מוסיף ומחדש זה שהריח ריח של א"א ע"ה כו'. ולהבין זה ילה"ק
משנת"ל ההפרש בין הקרבנות לקטרת דקרבנות הן בחי' לחם וכמ"ש את קרבני לחמי
לאשי וכמו הלחם שממשיך חיות הנפש ומחברו עם הגוף שמתחזקים כחותיו עי"ז
וכמא' עד דלא אכילנא כו' לא צלינא כו', ומ"מ אין בזה התחדשות החיות כו',
כמו"כ הקרבנות ממשיכים מבחי' אוא"ס דכי לא אדם הוא להתלבש בבחי' ציור
אדה"ע כו', מ"מ ההמשכה היא רק הארה לבד שבאה בבחי' צמצום באדה"ע כו',
והיא המשכת הארה השייכה להשתל' כו', אבל הקטרת הוא בחי' ריח שמשיב את
הנפש שממשיך מעצם חבור הנשמה עם הגוף ונמשך אור וחיות חדש כו', וכמו"כ
ענן הקטרת הוא שממשיך בחי' אוא"ס דכי לא אדם הוא שיאיר בגילוי ממש בבחי'
אדה"ע כו'. רטז) והנה עדיין צ"ל משנת"ל פרי"ג דקרבנות נק' לחם שזהו המשכת
או"פ לבד וקטרת הוא בחי' ריח שממשיך האו"מ כו', והלא בקרבנות כתיב ריח
ניחוח לה' הרי הקרבנות הן ג"כ בחי' ריח, וא"כ מהו ההפרש בין הקרבנות
והקטרת כו', דמאחר דשניהם הם בחי' ריח וא"כ מהו ההפרש ביניהם כו'. ולהבין
זה ילה"ק תחלה דכללות ענין הריח הוא מה שבא ע"י בירורי הניצוצות דתהו
כו', להיות ידוע דריח שרשו מבחי' הגבו' דוקא דהרי כל ריח הוא מדבר החזק
דוקא, דדבר הבלתי חזק לא יהי' ממנו ריח כ"א מדבר החזק וחריף, וכמו התבלין
שמתבלין בהם המאכלים שכולם המה דברים חריפים ומהם בא הריח כו'. דכמו"כ
הוא בנמשל דענין הריח הוא מבירורי הניצוצו' דתהו שהן בבחי' הגבו' בחי'
אורות תקיפים וחזקים כו', וכמארז"ל לעולם יהא אדם רך כקנה ואל יהא קשה
כארז, רך כקנה הן בחי' מדות דתקון שהן בבחי' חלישות ובבחי' מיעוט האור
כו', וקשה כארז הן מדות דתהו שהן בבחי' תוקף ובבחי' ריבוי האור כו', וזהו
הן בהאורות והן בהכלים
In the Torah portion of Noah, it is written, "And the Lord smelled the
pleasing aroma and said, 'I will never again curse the ground...'" The
Midrash Rabbah explains that this aroma was the scent of Abraham our
forefather ascending from the fiery furnace, and similarly, the scent
of Hananiah, Mishael, and Azariah ascending from the fiery furnace.
This raises a question: Why did the Lord respond with "I will never
again curse" specifically because of the scent of Abraham and
Hananiah, Mishael, and Azariah? On the surface, the pleasing aroma
refers to the sacrifices that Noah offered, which is also a profound
concept, as the mystery of the sacrifice ascends to the Infinite. What
is added and renewed by the fact that the Lord smelled the scent of
Abraham and the others?
To understand this, we need to first distinguish between the
sacrifices and the incense. Sacrifices are like bread, as it is
written, "My sacrifice, My bread for My offerings." Just as bread
sustains the soul and connects it to the body, strengthening its
faculties, and as the saying goes, "Until I have eaten, I do not
pray," similarly, sacrifices draw down the Infinite Light, which does
not manifest in the form of human likeness. However, this drawing down
is only a limited illumination that descends within the chain of
creation. On the other hand, the incense represents a scent that
revives the soul, drawing from the essential connection between the
soul and the body, bringing forth new light and vitality. The cloud of
incense draws the Infinite Light to manifest openly within the realm
of creation.
Yet, we still need to address the fact that sacrifices are referred to
as "a pleasing aroma to the Lord," indicating that sacrifices also
have the aspect of aroma. What, then, is the difference between
sacrifices and incense if both are considered aromas?
To understand this, we first need to establish that the concept of
aroma comes through the refinement of the sparks of Tohu (chaos). It
is known that aroma originates specifically from strength, as all
aromas derive from strong substances. Weak substances do not produce a
scent; only strong and sharp substances do, such as spices that are
used to season food, which are all sharp and from them comes the
scent. Similarly, in the spiritual realm, aroma comes from the
refinement of the sparks of Tohu, which are characterized by strong
lights. As the sages said, "A person should always be as soft as a
reed and not as hard as a cedar," where being soft as a reed refers to
the attributes of Tikkun (rectification) that are characterized by
weakness and diminished light. In contrast, being hard as a cedar
refers to the attributes of Tohu, which are characterized by strength
and abundant light. This applies to both the lights and the vessels.
Therefore, the sacrifices, which are considered as bread, draw only
the inner light (Ohr Pnimi), whereas the incense, which is considered
aroma, draws the encompassing light (Ohr Makif). This distinction
highlights why the incense, which represents a new and essential
vitality, was specifically associated with the eternal promise of "I
will never again curse the ground," due to its connection to the
powerful and enduring essence that transcends the limitations of
creation.

Source that Hashem knows everything, but still allows free choice, and it's not wrong to "regret", later, based on free choice actions:

ארדה נא וגו'. הנה הכצעקתה הוא לשון נקבה וכן הבאה. ועשו לשון נקבה ולשון
זכר. וגם להבין מהו ארדה נא ואראה הלא משמים הביט ה'. אך פי' הכצעקתה
היינו הצעקה העולה מבחי' מדת הדין שהיא בחי' מדת מלכות שנק' דין דינא
דמלכותא דינא רק שהוא דינא רפיא מלך במשפט יעמיד ארץ וז"ש הכצעקתה הבאה
וכמ"ש בערב היא באה. ורחל באה. וביאור הענין הנה מתחלה יש להקדים לשון
השגור בדחז"ל גלוי וידוע לפני מי שאמר והיה העולם. גלוי וידוע דייקא. כי
הנה הפילוסופים נלאו להשיג ענין ההשגחה פרטית כמו אין אדם נוקף אצבעו
מלמטה אא"כ מכריזין עליו מלמעלה דקשה להם כיון שהוא ית' יחיד ומיוחד אחד
האמת וא"כ איך יתכן ידיעת הש"י הפרטים וההשגחה פרטי' לתת דעתו על ענינים
רבים שהרי זה בחי' רבוי. וחז"ל כיוונו לתרץ זה בדבור אחד באמרם גלוי
וידוע לפני כו' שאין ידיעתו ית' כדמיון ידיעת האדם איזו דבר שדעתו השיג
הדבר ומתחלה לא ידעו וכשיודע הדבר הרי דעתו מלובשת בידיעה זו ומחשבה זו
שנותן דעתו להשיגה וקודם ידיעתו היה דעתו פנוי וה"ז בחי' שינוי והתפעלות
משא"כ למעלה ידיעתו ית' שיודע כל העולמות ופרטיהן אין הענין שדעתו מתלבשת
ונתפסת בזה אלא ע"ד גלוי וידוע שהכל גלוי וידוע לפניו ית' ממילא וא"צ
להיות נתפס ומתלבש בהדבר לידע (במכש"כ ממה שמחיה ומהווה הדבר שלא ע"י
התלבשות בהדבר כ"א על ידי היותו סוכ"ע. וכ"ש וק"ו שידיעת הדבר ופרטיו א"צ
להיות ע"י התלבשות ותפיסה בהדבר כו') וכיון שהוא גלוי וידוע אין שייך כלל
קושייתם שהוא בחי' רבוי כי זה אינו רק במין ידיעת האדם שא"א לו לידע דבר
כ"א ע"י שדעתו ומחשבתו מתלבשים בידיעת הדבר. וזהו כי לא מחשבותי
מחשבותיכם כו' כי הוא גלוי וידוע כו' (והמשכיל יבין דקות הדברים ולאו כל
מוחא סביל דא). והנה כתיב (זכרי' סי' ד') שבעה אלה עיני ה' המה משוטטים
בכל הארץ וכתיב (ד"ה ב' י"ו ט') כי ה' עיניו משוטטות בכל הארץ. ויש להבין
דענין משוטטים ומשוטטות משמע שנמשך לראות ולעיין הדבר על ידי ראיה זו
והרי זה כמו בחי' התלבשות בהדבר הנראה וידוע וזה לכאורה הפך ממ"ש בפי'
גלוי וידוע. אך הענין כי נודע שבע"ס יש אורות וכלים כי בחי' חו"ג זהו
בחי' כלי אבל האור הוא הארה מא"ס ב"ה דלאו מכל אינון מדות איהו כלל רק
שהאור מתלבש בהכלי שהוא חו"ג ושאר המדות שהן נקראים בחינת כלים שהם
מגבילים את האור ובהן ועל ידם נמשך האור להיות מחיה נבראים בע"ג להיות
התהוות מיכאל וגבריאל מחנה מיכאל מקבלים מבחי' חסד וגבריאל מבחי' גבורה
שא"א להיות המשכה זו מהאור עצמו כ"א ע"י הכלים. כמו שא"א להיות השפעת כסף
וזהב מהנשמה אא"כ מלובשת בגוף ונותנת הנשמה צדקה לעני ע"י היד הגשמי.
והנה כמו כן ע"י הכלים דע"ס הוא ג"כ בחי' העלאת הזכות וחוב של כל נברא כי
ע"י שהאדם עובר עבירה קונה לו קטיגור אחד נעשה פגם וכתם באותו המלאך
הממונה ע"ז כי יש מלאכים שמקבלים ממדה זו ויש ממדה זו כנ"ל בענין מיכאל
וגבריאל כו' ומלאך זה מעלה הדבר למלאך גבוה ממנו עד שמתעלה בכלים דע"ס
דמלכות דאצי' המתלבשים בבי"ע ובתוך הכלי מלובש האור מא"ס ב"ה. ונמצא ע"י
הכלים מתעלה להאור א"ס ב"ה המלובש בהכלים דע"ס. ולכן נאמר ע"ז עיניו
משוטטות שהוא בחי' הכלים דע"ס.
The passage begins with the phrase "I will go down and see..." Here,
the term "the outcry" is in a feminine form, as well as "coming." The
usage of both feminine and masculine forms needs to be understood.
Also, why does it say, "I will go down and see," when the Lord already
sees everything from the heavens?
The explanation begins with "the outcry," referring to a cry arising
from the attribute of justice, which is related to the attribute of
sovereignty called "the law of the kingdom." Although this law is
lenient, a king maintains the earth through justice. This is implied
by the phrase "the outcry that has come," referencing evening arrival,
as in the expressions "she came" and "Rachel came."
To elucidate this, let's first understand a common phrase in the
sayings of the sages: "Revealed and known before Him who spoke and the
world came into being." The philosophers struggled with the concept of
Divine providence, like the idea that no person stubs their toe below
unless it is decreed above. They found it challenging to reconcile
that, given His unity and singular truth, how could the Divine know
particulars and exercise providence over many details without implying
multiplicity?
The sages addressed this in one statement: "Revealed and known before
Him." Divine knowledge is not like human knowledge, where a person's
mind must grasp something it previously did not know. Human knowledge
involves a change and engagement with the known object, whereas Divine
knowledge is inherently revealed and known. All is revealed before Him
naturally, without the need for engagement or change.
Since it is all inherently revealed and known, the issue of
multiplicity does not arise, as it would with human knowledge, which
requires the mind to engage with and understand particulars. Divine
thoughts are not our thoughts, for everything is inherently known to
Him.
The scripture states in Zechariah 4:10, "These seven are the eyes of
the Lord, which roam to and fro through the whole earth," and in 2
Chronicles 16:9, "For the eyes of the Lord run to and fro throughout
the whole earth." The term "run to and fro" seems to suggest an active
observation, implying engagement with the seen objects, seemingly
contrary to the idea of inherent knowledge.
However, this can be understood by noting that within the ten sephirot
(spheres) there are both lights and vessels. Attributes like love and
judgment are vessels, whereas the light is an emanation from the
Infinite that transcends these attributes. The light becomes clothed
in the vessels, which define and limit it. This allows the light to
sustain beings appropriately, just as charity is given through a
physical hand, with the soul acting through the body.
Similarly, within the vessels of the ten sephirot, the merits and
faults of each creation are elevated. When a person sins, an
accusatory angel is created, affecting the angel overseeing that
matter. There are angels receiving from different attributes, like
Michael from kindness and Gabriel from severity. This process involves
the vessels of the ten sephirot of sovereignty within the worlds of
Beriah, Yetzirah, and Asiyah (Creation, Formation, and Action), where
the Infinite light is clothed.
Thus, the elevation to the Infinite light occurs through the vessels
of the ten sephirot. Therefore, the term "His eyes roam to and fro"
refers to the vessels of the ten sephirot.


You may consider posting your answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68273/how-can-g-d-regret-anything

@Deuteronomy interesting. It's allowed to just copy an answer and repost it?

I'd suggest slightly editing to tailor it to that context, and a linkback with a prefacing disclosure, but otherwise I don't see any reason that would prevent one from copying over their own answer where relevant. Doing so will also ensure that your answer will reach an appropriate audience in the event this is closed as a duplicate. You can always ask on the meta if there is any doubt: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/

"There is no wrong, everything is exactly as it should be," where in the Bible is this theology presented in a consistent way?

@Aaron your question as originally articulated did not specify that you are looking for a fleshed out theology directly from the text of Tanakh (as if there is such a thing). This answer is to the original iteration of your question.

@Aaron there is no such thing as the Bible. We are given the Torah, the written and oral Torah are one. They were and are being given together as one. You can't have one without the other.

Your opinion that they are one is fine. But the idea of Sephirot come what, close to a thousand years after the closing of the Bible? From an unsourced Mystical tradition? A tradition hat other Rabbis reject as a forgery. You are going to tell me that I have to accept a mystical answer rejected by parts of the Jewish world because everything HAD TO BE GIVEN AT ONCE AND IS INSEPARABLE. ? Really?

I'm not knocking your belief, I just don't see why you feel like I have to swallow your beliefs just for me to ask a question.

@Aaron it's not a belief, it's accepted as Judaism. This site is about Judaism. If you want to ask questions about other religions that don't accept the talmud and kabbalah, you can try other websites like the Christianity stack exchange

So a Dor Deah Jew that comes from a strong Yemenite tradition that rejects Kabbalah doesn't practice Judaism? Last I heard Ovadia Yosef served on a Beit Din with Rab Qapach who rejects the Zohar and Kabbalah. According to you a Karaite who doesn't follow Talmud isn't Jewish? An Ethiopian Jew who doesn't have the Talmud as part their tradition also doesn't practice Judaism? Can I just pick rules like you to disqualify groups of people? Like since the Rambam makes clear the Messiah can't be someone whose died, can we say Chabad doesn't practice Judaism?!

@Aaron you're confusing Jewish with Judaism. One is Jewish if and if his/her mother is Jewish OR converted according to halacha (which is outlined in the talmud, Rambam and commentators). This is regardless of whatever one believes or follows. There was an account where rav kapach was going to be a witness at a wedding, but since he didn't Believe in zohar, the other rav who was planning on officiating the wedding said "wow, the esteemed rav kapach! Why are you only the witness? You should be the rav doing the officiating! I'll be the witness you lead the wedding", in order to save the wedding

You and I disagree. I find Ethiopian Judaism to be a form of Judaism. Not the Ethiopians are Jews who practice a different religion

@Aaron if one's mother is jewish, or if one converted according to halacha, one is jewish. halacha is defined by the talmud and poskim etc.

@Awtsmoos--עצמות I would love to get your feedback/answer on another question here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/142931/is-there-any-synagogue-where-jews-still-do-full-sujood-prostration-all-year-ro/142941#142941
Only two Jewish groups maintain the Jewish practice of prostration and bowing as brought down in the Talmud. Karaites and Ethiopians. Are we allowed to learn how to bow and prostrate from them? Or no because they don't practice Judaism?

This isn't a comprehensive theological answer to your question, but I wanted to expound, from a logical perspective, on something another user mentioned.

It's explained that in order for Hashem to explain why that was
happening, He would have to "unravel" the entire universe back to it's
origins to show us why it should happen. Without all of that context,
it's impossible to know.

This resembles the logical concept of the 'Flatland.'
Most basically, the Flatland concept is that 2D objects are incapable of perceiving, comprehending, or experiencing the completeness of a 3D object because they have no plane of reference for it.
If you drew a 2D square and circle on paper and they became living, you would see their shapes, but when they look at each other they would only see a line in space.
If you poked your finger through the paper to make a hole, they would still only see a line. Although you're a 3D being interacting with their plane, they could only perceive and experience you in 2D.
I hope this is useful for putting our inability to fully comprehend the 'dimension' of the divine into perspective from a logical angle.

Deuteronomy 32:4 seems to imply that He cannot be wrong.

Can you quote the pasuk and any other relevant pesukim please?

I think there's a verse in Samuel about God not changing his mind like a man, that would probably improve your answer

Before I answer I want to clarify a few major points:
A: HASHEM knows the future. Not only that, but He Creates the future. Every single moment only exists because He actively Creates it. If He decided to stop Creating, the next moment of time would simply not come into existence. Thus, He has complete control over everything, every sequence of events, every thought, everything, and He also knows exactly what every moment will bring.
B: Even though this is true, He still gives us free will. The way this works is either extremely complex, or simply illogical; but it does work, and it is true. Thus, we have the ability to choose between decisions, between good and evil (see below).
C: HASHEM is the Creator of Good and Evil. He created these concepts such that certain things which are desired by Him for some super-logical reason are called “good”, and certain things which are despised by Him are called “bad”.
D: HASHEM is the Creator of the basic concepts of right, wrong, and regret. Thus, they don’t apply to Him.
Now, with those fundamentals, we can answer your inquiry:
Hashem, for some pre-logical reason, creates the universe. He gives us the ability to choose good and evil. He has every ability to force us to make certain choices, but He doesn’t, so the potential exists for people to subvert His Will.
He desires goodness. Therefore, He wants people to choose good decision over evil ones. However, people have a real potential to choose incorrectly, as in some instances recorded in Tanakh.
HASHEM knew, from the very beginning, that some people would eventually do evil. Still, He created them, for the same reason He Created everything in the first place (Again, this is above logic).
Thus, although the creation of those people is somehow necessary, they do still choose evil in the end. Because evil is defined as that which G-D despises, G-D dislikes the fact that those people exist to choose evil, and regrets their decision, not His own!

No sources at all, I will have to downvote until his is addressed :)

No sources at all, but also some of your dogmatic ideas don't have a strong basis in the Biblical tradition. For example, "HASHEM knew, from the very beginning, that some people would eventually do evil." I dunno man, God sure sounds surprised in the Garden of Eden story

I don't see how D logically follows. Senator Sanders voted for a tax bill and it still applies to him.

@doubleAA Senator Sanders didn’t invent the very concept of law, and thus the concept of law applies to him as well.

@Aaron, reread point A.

@QwertyCTRL. Genesis 1 relates how God doesn't create everything, the earth already exists in its chaotic way. And the Earth is actually the one that creates some life on earth. So I don't know that I would accept your A premise

@QwertyCTRL. And why does that follow? Einstein invented the very concept of general relativity and it applied to his mass as well.

@Aaron he was not surprised at all. See rashi

@Awtsmoos--עצמות which Rashi specifically?

@RabbiKaii on the  verse איכה, "where are you"? Hashem knew where they were, but He asked in order to allow them to do teshuva

@Awtsmoos--עצמות is that the surprise that Aaron as talking about?

@RabbiKaii looking back, I actually am not very sure. I assumed the surprise was hashem asking where they are and asking why they ate it. Is there another surprise possible?

@Awtsmoos--עצמות I figured he was talking about the surprise that they ate the fruit, but I'll let Aaron clarify

I was discussing the fruit. And I want to be clear that I'm not inherently against the idea that God knows all things etc etc. I would just like an answer that shows that idea consistently in the Bible. Rather than quoting Talmud, Rambam, and any commentator who de facto rejects God as being wrong or not knowing things as part of their theology. Rambams theology ignores a lot of hard passages that get written off as dreams, rather than having to explain them

In other words. Giving me a bunch of Rabbis who explain that God has no emotions, when I can look from the beginning of the Bible to the end of the Bible and see God's emotions written everywhere isn't satisfying. If I rewrote and reinterpreted the entire Bible I too could come up with theological statements about the perfection of God and His Inability to be wrong

@Aaron you said "Rather than quoting Talmud, Rambam, and any commentator" that's IS what the Torah is: talmud, Rambam, commentators. If you want to discuss the "Bible" then you need to go to the Christianity stack exchange. In Judaism, we discuss the Torah, which was given together with it's explanation, which is the talmud, Rambam, commentators etc etc.

I understand that you are of the opinion that Torah, Talmud, and Rambam/Commentators are not separate and they were all given together. That's your perogative. I'm just letting you know it's not satisfying. If I told you that every hard to understand passage in the Bible could ONLY be a dream, no other possible interpretation, because Rambam said so, would you then sit down and say "Well I guess there can never be a different opinion for the rest of time." ?
